# JavaScript in Google Tag Manager, "=" outputting as "\x3d", how to fix?

Tags: javascript, escaping, google-tag-manager

The tag is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var foo = "="
</script>
```

But when I view this in preview mode it shows:

```
<script type="text/gtmscript>
    var foo = "\x3d"
</script>
```

I'm completely lost on this one, this is in a "Custom HTML Tag".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to escape the "=" like `"\="`? I thought one way, but it's a too ugly workaround that possible works. 

You can use `var foo = decodeURIComponent("%3D")`

Comment: I have tried "\=", I have no idea why it doesn't work though.

Comment: Why do you feel this needs fixing ?  "\x3d" is the hex representation for an equals sign. This should work without problems, even if it looks funny.

Comment: well it's supposed to be implementing a tracking code, and the tracking code isn't working. This is a nondescript example, what's really happening is the variable is supposed to kick out a dynamic url. So instead of kicking out "https://test.com/?param=123&param2=456" it's kicking out "https://test.com/?param\x3d123\x26param2\x3d456" (or something like that, I don't remember exactly what the ampersand was escaping as). 

I think this is why the tracker isn't working but I'm not positive

Answer (score 0):

Use these instructions

```
$('[attribute$="value"]')
```